# High performance multi tenant database migration solution

Tags: database, deployment, migration, database-migration, multi-tenant

We have a multi tenant system with 1000 databases. We want to migration all the database instantly when deploying new release as part of deployment process.

Migration solution provided by framework like Laravel or other provides solution to loop through database to apply migration but this solution is slow keeping in mind the no of databases it needs to run on.

Is there any solution where this can be done instantly?

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to divide the migration script in chucks and run them in parallel but was thinking if there is any better solution